# Unable to Install Zend Server 6 on Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, zend-server, zend-server-installation

I am unable to install Zend Server 6 on an Amazon EC2 instance running Red Hat 4.6.3-2.

This error is shown when I run: sudo yum install zend-server-php-5.4 in a terminal.

```
Transaction check error:
file /usr/local/zend/var/log conflicts between attempted installs of zend-server-php-5.4-common-6.1.0-95.x86_64 and mod-php-5.4-apache2-zend-server-5.4.16-24.x86_64
```

Also tried deleting the directory: "/usr/local/zend" and restarting the server.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean Red Hat 6.4

Comment: Sorry. Its version 6.4. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just worked around this problem by installing the Zend Server packages in pieces.

First, install just the common package:

```
$ sudo yum install zend-server-php-5.4-common
```

Next, download the RPM files for mod-php and zend-server*:

```
$ wget http://repos-source.zend.com/zend-server/6.2/rpm/x86_64/mod-php-5.4-apache2-zend-server-5.4.21-2.x86_64.rpm
$ wget http://repos-source.zend.com/zend-server/6.2/rpm/x86_64/zend-server-php-5.4-6.2.0-314.x86_64.rpm
```

Finally, using RPM instead of YUM, I installed the zend-server and mod-php packages directly using the --replacefiles option as follows:

```
sudo rpm -ivh zend-server-php-5.4-6.2.0-314.x86_64.rpm mod-php-5.4-apache2-zend-server-5.4.21-2.x86_64.rpm --replacefiles
```

Not sure what will happen down the line but so far it's working well.

- The wget file is subject to change - the repo is still up - but the versions on the files are different.

Comment: Just realized that you'll be unable to update the package automatically via yum after this. However, I don't see why the same steps couldn't be repeated again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what zend is but I followed their [documentation](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-6/zend-server.htm#rpm_installing_zend_server.htm) and was able to install it successfully. Here are my steps:

created an EC2 instnace for RHEL6.4 64 bit using `ami-b8a63b88`

updated `/etc/yum.repos.d/zend.repo` as below:

```
[Zend]
name=zend-server
baseurl=http://repos.zend.com/zend-server/6.1/rpm/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://repos.zend.com/zend.key

[Zend_noarch]
name=zend-server - noarch
baseurl=http://repos.zend.com/zend-server/6.1/rpm/noarch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://repos.zend.com/zend.key
```

Installed zend server by running command: `yum -y install zend-server-php-5.4.x86_64`

It took about 10 minutes to complete the installation. Also it installed 68 packages in total including the dependancies.

Once done, I could see that Zend is listening on 10081 and 10082:

```
# netstat -anp | grep 1008
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10081               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2177/lighttpd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10082               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2177/lighttpd
```

It was a smooth installation process for me even though I do not know anything about Zend. If installing Zend is what you are working on, then these steps should get you going.

hope this helps.